# Autowire not working in Spring boot Forms

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

Im new to spring boot and found an issue when trying to use a service inside a class i created to validate forms

i created a validator class to validate form as mention here

https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

It works as expected

```
package com.nexill.bank.form.user;


import com.nexill.bank.entity.User;
import com.nexill.bank.repository.UserRepository;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Component
@Configurable
public class UserForm {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Email(message = "Must be a valid email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email cannot be empty")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Password cannot be empty")
    @Size(min=6, max=30, message = "Password need to be between 6 to 30 characters")
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Confirm password cannot be empty")
    @Size(min=6, max=30, message = "Confirm password need to be between 6 to 30 characters")
    private String confirmPassword;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    @AssertTrue(message = "Password and confirm password need to match")
    public boolean isDifferentPass() {
        return !password.equals(confirmPassword) ? false : true;
    }

    @AssertTrue(message = "Email already exists")
    public boolean isUniqueEmailForUser() {
        User x = userRepository.findUserByEmail(getEmail());
        return (x) == null;
    }
}
```

The issue is im getting HV000090: Unable to access isUniqueEmailForUser.

when i invastigated the repository is null.I have used userRepository other places in the system with autowire and it works as expected.

The main package is package com.nexill.bank.What am i missing.

The form is used in the controller like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/adminDashboard/user", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView adminDashboardAddUserPost(ModelAndView modelAndView, @Valid UserForm userForm,  BindingResult bindingResult) {
        modelAndView.addObject("currentUser", authenticationFacade.getUser());
        modelAndView.addObject("userForm", userForm);
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            User user = new User(userForm);
            user.setRole(roleService.getRepository().findByName("BANK_STAFF"));
            userService.createUser(user);
            ModelAndView redirectModelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/adminDashboard");
            redirectModelAndView.addObject("saveStatus" , true);
            return redirectModelAndView;
        }
        modelAndView.setViewName("adminDashboard/user");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create the object? I guess you are trying to validate the object in a controller but in this case the object is not a bean but created from request. So the repository is not autowired.

Comment: Hi StanislavL question is updated with the code in the controller as i understand the form is also injected here.I'm not sure of the underlying behaviour.Hope this helps to clear the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment in your case you have just a POJO instance not a bean here. So no beans could be autowired here.

Instead you can add a custom constraint and provide a Validator with injected bean.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface MyConstraint {
}
```

The validator where you can inject your bean

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;

public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator {

    @Autowired;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    ...
}
```

Got the code from the link

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints

Comment: Thank you very much